# Update div in html using Ajax function failed

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to display the search result of my page under the the search area. So I used AJAX to display the result in a div. but I could'nt get it work.

I have three main pieces, the div, the searchResult page and the ajax function

```
<input type="text" name="studentName">
<button type="submit" name="searchByName" onclick='get_info();'>بحث</button>

  <div id="searchResult"><b></b></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function get_info() { // Call to ajax function


  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "NameSearchResult.php", // Name of the php files
    data: {name: <?php echo $_POST['studentName']; ?>},
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#searchResult").html(html);
    }
  });
 }
```

and my search Page:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbConfigBDO.php';

$studentName = $_POST["name"];
$counter=0;
$emptyString = "لايوجد";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row_count = $result->rowCount();
if ($row_count > 0){
  ..........  }
```

Now when I search nothing appears, although it works when I put all the code in one page (which would be messy in term of the appearance of the result!).

Comment: Based on your code you want to update HTML after pressing button, right? So, where's your `get_info()` JS function? Also, if you are not redirected with POST on this page, you can't take `$_POST['studentName']` because there's no request. You should take that field using `$('#student-name').val()` and set the `id="student-name"` to your input.

Comment: Sorry I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

From function return the output as per below:
return json_encode($result);

In ajax call use **dataType:"json"** and show your html

Example ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",

dataType:"json",

url: "NameSearchResult.php", // Name of the php files

data: {name: $("#studentName").val()},

success: function(html)
```

Comment: it gives an error message: json_encode is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

change code like this

```
<input type="text" name="studentName" id="studentName">
<button type="submit" name="searchByName" onclick='get_info();'>بحث</button>

  <div id="searchResult"><b></b></div>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "NameSearchResult.php", // Name of the php files
    data: {name: $("#studentName").val()},
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#searchResult").html(html);
    }
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I did add the id part and changed AJAX data but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

inside ajax success method try catch what you are getting

```
success: function(html)
{
   console.log(html);

}
```

if you getting something then your code must be work.

Comment: see in your browser console. What you getting in your ajax response it will show there .

Comment: From function return the output as per below:
return json_encode($result);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "NameSearchResult.php", // Name of the php files
    data: {name: $("#studentName").val()},
    success: function(html)

Comment: something comes very quickly then disappear.

Comment: can you provide the code what are you trying to return .

Comment: success: function(html)
{
   console.log(html);

}

Comment: @sabbirchowdury I used the one in your answer.